# Audio merging using OpenSL ES Android

Tags: java, android, c++, audio, opensl

I am trying to record my vocals and then merge them with an audio file together using OPENSL ES Library. I found this GitHub sample called [Native-Audio](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/native-audio). It merges the two audios. But the background audio file is playing much faster than the actual rate in the final output.

Please use headphones to notice the difference.

**Samples Links:** [Before](https://vocaroo.com/i/s1w9uhr0o1VQ) and [After](https://vocaroo.com/i/s0BI77V5JocK)

Also, it uses the files from the assets folder only. How can I manually select MP3 files from file manager?

```
private void mixAudio(){
    try {
        if (!(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) ||
                !(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
        {
            // Show rationale and request permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    1000);

        }
        else {

            buttonMix.setEnabled(false);
            buttonMix.setText("MIXING....");
            textViewMixPath.setText("");
            buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);
            buttonRecord.setEnabled(false);

            buttonStart.setEnabled(false);
            listView.setEnabled(false);

            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try{
//final File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/" + "mix.wav");
                        //String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                        //File file = new File(baseDir  + "/mix.wav");

                        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/VocalRecorder";
                        File fileParent = new File(path);
                        if (!fileParent.exists()){
                            fileParent.mkdir();
                        }

                        final File file = new File(fileParent.getPath()  + "/mix.wav");

                        //String author = getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider";
                        //Uri videoUri = FileProvider.get(this, author, mediaFile);

                        //final File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/" + "mix.wav");

                        //MediaMuxer muxer = new MediaMuxer(file.getAbsolutePath(), MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);

                        String beat = beats[selectedBeat];
                        //beat = beat.replace(".wav", ".mp3");

                        AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd(beat);

                        MediaCodec codec = null;
                        //ByteBuffer outputBuffer;
                        //short[] data; // data for the AudioTrack playback
                        //int outputBufferIndex = -1;


                        MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                        mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                        String durationStr = mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
                        final long duration = Long.parseLong(durationStr);

                        MediaExtractor extractor = new MediaExtractor();
                        extractor.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                        // right now I am pointing to a URI but I have tested that both will
                        // play the media file using MediaPlayer

                        int sampleRate = 0;
                        int numChannels = 0;
                        int dstIndex = -1;
                        int numTracks = extractor.getTrackCount(); //This says 1
                        for (int i = 0; i < numTracks; ++i) { // so this will just run once
                            MediaFormat format = extractor.getTrackFormat(i); // getting info so it looks good so far
                            String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME); // "audio/mpeg"

                            if (mime.startsWith("audio/")) {
                                extractor.selectTrack(i);
                                codec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
                                codec.configure(format, null, null, 0);

                                //format.setString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME, MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_AUDIO_AMR_NB);
                                //dstIndex = muxer.addTrack(format);

                                //writer.setFrameRate(format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE));
                                //writer.setSamplesPerFrame(format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT));
                                //writer.setBitsPerSample(16);

                                sampleRate = format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE);
                                numChannels = format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT);

                                break;
                            }

                        }

                        // Calculate the number of frames required for specified duration
                        long numFrames = (long)(duration * sampleRate/1000);

                        // Create a wav file with the name specified as the first argument
                        WavFile wavFile = WavFile.newWavFile(file, numChannels, numFrames, 16, sampleRate);


                        if (codec == null) {
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No decoder for file format");
                        }

                        //ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = decoder.getInputBuffers();
                        //ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();



        /*
        Boolean eosReceived = false;
        while (!eosReceived) {
            int inIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(1000);
            if (inIndex >= 0) {
                ByteBuffer buffer = decoder.getInputBuffer(inIndex);
                int sampleSize = extractor.readSampleData(buffer, 0);
                if (sampleSize < 0) {
                    // We shouldn't stop the playback at this point, just pass the EOS
                    // flag to mDecoder, we will get it again from the
                    // dequeueOutputBuffer
                    Log.d("DecodeActivity", "InputBuffer BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM");
                    decoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, 0, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);

                } else {
                    decoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, sampleSize, extractor.getSampleTime(), 0);
                    extractor.advance();
                }

                int outIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, 1000);
                switch (outIndex) {
                    case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED:
                        Log.d("DecodeActivity", "INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED");
                        //outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();
                        break;

                    case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
                        MediaFormat format = decoder.getOutputFormat();
                        Log.d("DecodeActivity", "New format " + format);
                        //audioTrack.setPlaybackRate(format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE));

                        break;
                    case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
                        Log.d("DecodeActivity", "dequeueOutputBuffer timed out!");
                        break;

                    default:
                        ByteBuffer outBuffer = decoder.getOutputBuffer(outIndex);
                        Log.v("DecodeActivity", "We can't use this buffer but render it due to the API limit, " + outBuffer);

                        final byte[] chunk = new byte[info.size];
                        outBuffer.get(chunk); // Read the buffer all at once
                        outBuffer.clear(); // ** MUST DO!!! OTHERWISE THE NEXT TIME YOU GET THIS SAME BUFFER BAD THINGS WILL HAPPEN

                        //audioTrack.write(chunk, info.offset, info.offset + info.size); // AudioTrack write data
                        decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex, false);
                        break;
                }

                // All decoded frames have been rendered, we can stop playing now
                if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                    Log.d("DecodeActivity", "OutputBuffer BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        */


                        short recordedData[] = recordedData();
                        int recordMixStartIndex = -1;

                        //muxer.start();

                        codec.start();
                        Boolean sawInputEOS = false;

                        MediaCodec.BufferInfo info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
                        MediaCodec.BufferInfo infoMux = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();

                        int count  = 0;

                        while (!sawInputEOS) {
                            int inputBufIndex = codec.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_US);
                            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "inputBufIndex : " + inputBufIndex);

                            if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {
                                ByteBuffer dstBuf = codec.getInputBuffer(inputBufIndex);

                                int sampleSize = extractor.readSampleData(dstBuf, 0);
                                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "sampleSize : " + sampleSize);
                                long presentationTimeUs = 0;
                                if (sampleSize < 0) {
                                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Saw input end of stream!");
                                    sawInputEOS = true;
                                    sampleSize = 0;
                                } else {
                                    presentationTimeUs = extractor.getSampleTime();
                                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "presentationTimeUs " + presentationTimeUs);
                                }

                                codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex,
                                        0, //offset
                                        sampleSize,
                                        presentationTimeUs,
                                        sawInputEOS ? MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM : 0);
                                if (!sawInputEOS) {
                                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "extractor.advance()");
                                    extractor.advance();

                                }
                            }


                            final int res = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, TIMEOUT_US);
                            if (res >= 0) {
                                int outputBufIndex = res;
                                ByteBuffer buf = codec.getOutputBuffer(outputBufIndex);

                                //final byte[] chunk = new byte[info.size];
                                //buf.get(chunk); // Read the buffer all at once

                                short[] shortArray = new short[info.size/2];
                                buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(shortArray);

                                buf.clear(); // ** MUST DO!!! OTHERWISE THE NEXT TIME YOU GET THIS SAME BUFFER BAD THINGS WILL HAPPEN



                                if (shortArray.length > 0) {
                                    //mAudioTrack.write(chunk, 0, chunk.length);
                                    //infoMux.presentationTimeUs = info.presentationTimeUs;
                                    //infoMux.flags = info.flags;

                                    //muxer.writeSampleData(dstIndex, ByteBuffer.wrap(chunk),
                                    //        infoMux);

                                    long []longData = new long[shortArray.length];

                                    // Merge data with vocal

                                    // Calculate the time
                                    final long bufferTimer = info.presentationTimeUs/1000;

                                    int vocalCount = 0;

                                    for (int i = 0; i < shortArray.length; i ++) {
                                        //writer.writeShortLittle(shortArray[i]);

                                        long offsetTime = i*1000/(sampleRate*2); // 2 channels
                                        Boolean mixed = false;
                                        if ((offsetTime + bufferTimer > recordStartTime) && (offsetTime + bufferTimer <= recordStopTime + 500)){
                                            if (recordMixStartIndex == -1){
                                                recordMixStartIndex = 0;
                                            }

                                            if (recordMixStartIndex < recordedData.length){
                                                //Log.i("TAG", "############ mix record data: " + recordMixStartIndex);

                                                longData[i] = TPMixSamples((int)(recordedData[recordMixStartIndex]), (int)shortArray[i]/3);

                                            if (vocalCount >= 3) {
                                                    recordMixStartIndex++;
                                                    vocalCount = 0;
                                                }
                                                else{
                                                    vocalCount ++;
                                                }
                                                mixed = true;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            // All done, set sawInputEOS to stop mixing
                                            if (bufferTimer > recordStopTime + 500){
                                                sawInputEOS = true;
                                            }
                                        }

                                        if (!mixed) {
                                            longData[i] = shortArray[i];
                                        }
                                    }


                                    Log.i("TAG", "############ write frames: " + longData.length/2);

                                    wavFile.writeFrames(longData, longData.length/2);

                                    count ++;
                                    if (count % 5 == 0){
                                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                long percent = bufferTimer*100/duration;
                                                buttonMix.setText("MIXING..." + percent + "%");
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }

                                }
                                codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufIndex, false /* render */);

                                if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                                    sawInputEOS = true;
                                }
                            } else if (res == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
                                //codecOutputBuffers = codec.getOutputBuffers();
                            } else if (res == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                                final MediaFormat oformat = codec.getOutputFormat();
                                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Output format has changed to " + oformat);
                                //mAudioTrack.setPlaybackRate(oformat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE));
                            }


                        }


                        // Close the wavFile
                        wavFile.close();
                        //                muxer.stop();
                        //                muxer.release();

                        codec.stop();
                        codec.release();
                        extractor.release();

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                buttonMix.setText("MIX DONE");
                                buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
                                buttonRecord.setEnabled(true);
                                textViewMixPath.setText(file.getPath());
                                buttonStart.setEnabled(true);
                                listView.setEnabled(true);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){

                    }
                }
            });

            thread.start();


        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private final int INT16_MIN = - 32768;
private final int INT16_MAX = 32767;


private long TPMixSamples(int a, int b) {
    if (a > INT16_MAX) {a = INT16_MAX;}
    if (a < INT16_MIN) {a = INT16_MIN;}

    return
            // If both samples are negative, mixed signal must have an amplitude between the lesser of A and B, and the minimum permissible negative amplitude
            a < 0 && b < 0 ?
                    ((int)a + (int)b) - (((int)a * (int)b)/INT16_MIN) :

                    // If both samples are positive, mixed signal must have an amplitude between the greater of A and B, and the maximum permissible positive amplitude
                    ( a > 0 && b > 0 ?
                            ((int)a + (int)b) - (((int)a * (int)b)/INT16_MAX)

                            // If samples are on opposite sides of the 0-crossing, mixed signal should reflect that samples cancel each other out somewhat
                            :
                            a + b);
}

/** Native methods, implemented in jni folder */
public static native void createEngine();
public static native void createBufferQueueAudioPlayer(int sampleRate, int samplesPerBuf);

/////
public static native boolean createAssetAudioPlayer(AssetManager assetManager, String filename);
// true == PLAYING, false == PAUSED
public static native void setPlayingAssetAudioPlayer(boolean isPlaying);

public static native int getDurationAssetAudioPlayer();
public static native int getCurrentPositionAssetAudioPlayer();

//////
public static native boolean createUriAudioPlayer(String uri);
public static native void setPlayingUriAudioPlayer(boolean isPlaying);
public static native void setLoopingUriAudioPlayer(boolean isLooping);
public static native void setChannelMuteUriAudioPlayer(int chan, boolean mute);
public static native void setChannelSoloUriAudioPlayer(int chan, boolean solo);
public static native int getNumChannelsUriAudioPlayer();
public static native void setVolumeUriAudioPlayer(int millibel);
public static native void setMuteUriAudioPlayer(boolean mute);
public static native void enableStereoPositionUriAudioPlayer(boolean enable);
public static native void setStereoPositionUriAudioPlayer(int permille);
public static native boolean selectClip(int which, int count);
public static native  void stopClip();
public static native boolean enableReverb(boolean enabled);
public static native boolean createAudioRecorder();
public static native void startRecording();
public static native void stopRecording();
public static native void pauseRecording();
public static native void resumeRecording();
public static native short[] recordedData();
public static native double recordedDuration();
public static native void shutdown();

/** Load jni .so on initialization */
static {
    System.loadLibrary("native-audio-jni");
}
```